# Print from where LogWriter was called in PJSIP example (PJSUA2)

Tags: java, android, pjsip

With the PJSUA2 example for android, the MyApp.java class have a log printer:

```
class MyLogWriter extends LogWriter
{
    public String appLabel = "PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)";

    @Override
    public void write(LogEntry entry) {
        Log.i(appLabel, "LW("+entry.getLevel()+") Msg: " + entry.getMsg());
    }
}
```

extended from "LogWriter" class:

```
package org.pjsip.pjsua2;

public class LogWriter {
  private long swigCPtr;
  protected boolean swigCMemOwn;

  protected LogWriter(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(LogWriter obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  protected void finalize() {
    delete();
  }

  public synchronized void delete() {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
      if (swigCMemOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = false;
        pjsua2JNI.delete_LogWriter(swigCPtr);
      }
      swigCPtr = 0;
    }
  }

  protected void swigDirectorDisconnect() {
    swigCMemOwn = false;
    delete();
  }

  public void swigReleaseOwnership() {
    swigCMemOwn = false;
    pjsua2JNI.LogWriter_change_ownership(this, swigCPtr, false);
  }

  public void swigTakeOwnership() {
    swigCMemOwn = true;
    pjsua2JNI.LogWriter_change_ownership(this, swigCPtr, true);
  }

  public void write(LogEntry entry) {
    pjsua2JNI.LogWriter_write(swigCPtr, this, LogEntry.getCPtr(entry), entry);
  }

  public LogWriter() {
    this(pjsua2JNI.new_LogWriter(), true);
    pjsua2JNI.LogWriter_director_connect(this, swigCPtr, swigCMemOwn, true);
  }

}
```

It does print a very complete log,

```
07-02 09:22:13.791: I/PJSUA (MyApp - MyLogWriter)(21597): LW(1) Msg: 09:22:13.788 sip_transport.  Error processing 575 bytes packet from UDP 107.170.134.248:5060 : PJSIP syntax error exception when parsing 'To' header on line 5 col 38:
```

and by that I know that my problem is in a parsing, the catch is, in wich file?
The PJSUA have 203 .java files, none of them called 'sip_transport'.

Is there a way to make this log show me from where it was called? Or any other way to find this parsing problem source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the calling method details using the `stacktrace` of the thread.

```
StackTraceElement caller = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1];

caller.getClassName();
caller.getMethodName();
caller.getFileName();
caller.getLineNumber();
```

Note that the **1st** index is picked because **0** is the current method (top of stack), and it goes down with each calling method. So you can pick any caller in the stack you want.

Comment: can you please help in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738485/make-call-above-api-18-using-pjsip