# Make call above API 18 using PJSIP

Tags: android, call, pjsip

After wasting lots of time on internet i'm expecting problem will be solve from here.

I'm using `org.pjsip.pjsua2` to make a call. It works fine for **API <=18** but for **API > 18** i'm unable to place a call. What may be the problem.

Comment: What is the behavior you are seeing? Did you check your logcat? Was there any information in there? Post the logcat if so... There's no where near the required information to debug your problem...

Comment: i did not see any logcat. Is there any field or problem in pjsua2 to make this problem?